# C program for number factors - "Floating point exception" error

Tags: c

I'm trying to find the factors of the number `b` but it's giving me an error `Floating point exception`. What's wrong?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){

  int i, b;

  scanf("%d", &b);

  for (i = 0; i < b; i++){

      if (b % i == 0){
          printf("%d ", i);
      }

  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Ahh, so starting from i = 1. thanks

Comment: when a user runs the posted code, they are left with a blank screen, with no indication of what they are expected to do.  Strongly suggest prompting the user before calling the `scanf()` function